# Chmod Permission denied

Tags: kali-linux, chmod

I want to install dvwa on Kali Linux but I am unable to install it.

These steps I have performed:

I have moved folder dvwa  to the `/var/www/html/`.

But when I type this command in terminal

```
# chmod -R 755 dvwa. 
Permission denied.
```

[image]

Comment: https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux

Comment: Please do not use screenshots when copy/paste is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You should execute the `chmod` command for the folder `dvwa` which is in `/var/www/html/dvwa` not on `/dvwa` which indeed doesn't exists.

```
cd /var/www/html/

chmod -R 755 dvwa
```

Comment: @MAyoub - if my answer solve your question please [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it

Answer (score 0):

When your working directory is the directory which contains the folder or file you can use the

relative Path

```
chmod -R 755 dvwa
```

or with absolute Path

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/dvwa
```

You try to change a data directly under /, which doesn't exist.

Comment: You've a typo there `htlm` > `html`